# How to level of JSON data with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an example JSON object like this

```js
[ { level: 1, first_name: 'Sammy', last_name: 'Snow' },
  { level: 2, cloth: 'shirt', color: 'red' },
  { level: 2, cloth: 'jeans', color: 'blue' },
  { level: 1, first_name: 'Danny', last_name: 'Crow' },
  { level: 2, cloth: 't-shirt', color: 'gray' },
  { level: 2, cloth: 'hat', color: 'white' },
  { level: 2, cloth: 'socks', color: 'yellow' } ]
```

Now when I send it to data base it looks like

[image]

I want to change it with javascript like this

```js
[{"level": 1,
  "first_name" : "Sammy",
  "last_name" : "Snow",
  "next_level" : 
  [{
  "level": 2,
  "cloth" : "shirt",
  "color" : "red"
  },
  {
  "level": 2,
  "cloth" : "jeans",
  "color" : "blue"
  }]
},
{"level": 1,
 "first_name" : "Danny",
 "last_name" : "Crow",
 "next_level" : 
 [{
  "level": 2,
  "cloth" : "t-shirt",
  "color" : "gray"
  },
 {
 "level": 2,
 "cloth" : "hat",
 "color" : "white"
 },
{
 "level": 2,
 "cloth" : "socks",
 "color" : "yellow"
 }]
}]
```

The result I want to send to data base and see as table
[image]

Now I have no ideas how to do this. Maybe is it possible to do in the database with SQL request than change structure with javascript?
Sorry, I'm very new in javascript.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a Map to keep level1 data and then iterate throw the data to structure it

```js
  dataq=[ { level: 1, first_name: 'Sammy', last_name: 'Snow' },
  { level: 2, cloth: 'shirt', color: 'red' },
  { level: 2, cloth: 'jeans', color: 'blue' },
  { level: 1, first_name: 'Danny', last_name: 'Crow' },
  { level: 2, cloth: 't-shirt', color: 'gray' },
  { level: 2, cloth: 'hat', color: 'white' },
  { level: 2, cloth: 'socks', color: 'yellow' } ]

map = new Map()
  x=dataq.forEach(x=>{if (x.first_name) x.next_level=[], map.set(x.first_name,x)})
  for(let i=0;i<dataq.length;i++){
    if(dataq[i].hasOwnProperty("first_name")) { l= map.get(dataq[i].first_name);continue}
     else  l.next_level.push(dataq[i])
    
  }
  console.log([...map.values()])
```